# Filtering a multi dimensional array with indices using broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy

I am wondering whether there is a way to filter a multidimensional array with an list of indexes.

For example, if there is a **multidimensional array** as so `[[40,60,15],[25,30,45]]`, I want to obtain the resulting values when you filter with the following index `[(0,2),(1,0)]`. Note that the index is a **list of tuples**

Note : I am trying to find out the fastest method of doing this. I managed to do this using a for loop and map + lambda function,
however was wondering if numpy broadcasting was a possibility?

```
 from numpy import np

 some_arr = np.array([40,60,15],[25,30,45])
 some_idx = [(0,2),(1,0)]
 
 #Method 1 : Using for loop
 new_list = []
 for idx in some_idx:
     new_list.append(some_arr[idx])

 # Method 2: Using lambda
 new_list = list(map(lambda idx : some_arr[idx], some_idx))

 # Method 3 : Using numpy ??? (i get an error ofcourse but this is what I tried to do)
 new_arr = some_arr[some_idx]
```

And I end up with an error for method 3 : `index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2`
The output for this example should be [15,25]

Comment: Same issue here. Can't find a way to simply filter a (x,3) shape ndarray.

Answer (score 2):

Use `zip` to instead have tuple of `((x_0, x_1...),(y_0,y_1...))` indices, which you can then use to perform integer array indexing along both axes:

```
some_arr = np.array([[40,60,15],[25,30,45]])
some_idx = [(0,2),(1,0)]

some_arr[tuple(zip(*some_idx))]
# array([15, 25])
```

---

Comparing with your first method:

```
new_list = []
for idx in some_idx:
    new_list.append(some_arr[idx])

np.array_equal(new_list, some_arr[tuple(zip(*some_idx))])
# True
```